# Oracle Apex sample projects help and code

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am new in oracle apex...
can any one tell me that from which site I can get oracle apex sample and professiona(running) Projects which are deployed in the companies .From that we can learn a lot that how the professional we can write the code.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a bunch of packaged applications, but it seems you are out of luck right now:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/packaged-apps-090453.html

You *can* find the standard sample application there.

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of commercial APEX applications on the OTN APEX website [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-com-commercial-apps-094049.html).  I don't imagine they let you look at their code though.